# pigpio Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid

Tags: pigpio

Trying to run the pigpio example program freq_count_1 I get the error 
`Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid`. The gpiotest program, however, runs as expected. Below you can see what I did. I have a Raspberry Pi 2 running Jessie.

```
gcc -Wall -pthread -o freq_count_1 freq_count_1.c -lpigpio -lrt`
rm -f /var/run/pigpiod.pid`
./freq_count_1 4 7 -r2 -s2`
```

- Monitoring GPIO pins: 4 and 7
- Sample rate 2: micros
- refresh rate 2 deciseconds

2015-11-27 13:47:24 initInitialise: `Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid`

Comment: I'm getting this problem when killing my program ungracefully. It seems the missing `gpioTerminate()` call in the end causes a file lock not to get unlocked or so. Don't have a fix yet, do you?

Answer (score 22):

You need to stop the pigpio daemon if you run a program directly linked with the pigpio C library.

In effect your program becomes the pigpio daemon and only one may be running at a time.

So

```
sudo killall pigpiod
```

Then run your C program.

While your C program is running it acts as the daemon, so you can still run gpiotest and any of the pigs commands, e.g. pigs pigpv (software version), pigs hwver (hardware version), pigs t (current tick).

Comment: Many thanks for a rapid and clear answer that did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out which other process is using it. Then kill that process.

This issue is documented on the FAQ page linked below:

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/faq.html#Cant_initialise_pigpio_library

Comment: The command `ps aux | grep pigpiod`can be replaced with `pgrep pigpiod`